# Charge injection Compensation for Demodulation

Tags: multiplexer, instrumentation-amplifier, charge, demodulation, switched-capacitor

I have a precision application where I am trying to limit the charge injection on an analog mux that is demodulating a sine wave from 0deg and 180deg components (with a trigger signal from a comparator).
Is there anyway to add a compensation circuit to guarantee that charge injection glitches will be kept to a minimum?

See the below background info:

Simplified Schematic:
[image]
Below is a more complete design. I have a simple instrumentation amplifier with its 0 and 180 components going into an analog mux. (Note: VDD=+5V and Vee=-5V). The output of the demodulated signal is going to a Low pass filter.

I have chosen the ADG1436 as the analog mux for its low On resistance, low charge injection (30pC) and low leakage.

Detailed Schematic: Cmult=2, Rfv and RF2v=1k, RGv=500, Cf =1.2p
[image]

The simulations look great and show no noticeable charge injection glitches.
But there is a slight offset upon a switch, which I think is macromodel modeling of charge injection? (see pink signal = Vdemod - input signals) But the ~8mV offset doesn't line up with Q/C=V  ==> Vcharge = 30pC/(6.8nF*2) = 2.2mV

ADG1436 Simulation:
[image]
When I built an earlier circuit with a different mux the ADG613 (made into a SPDT), with 1pC charge injection, the simulations also showed no noticeable glitches on the output or inputs to the mux. Yet as seen below there are noticeable spikes.
So I think the macromodels isn't really showing the maximum charge injection that could occur!

Inverted Demodulated signal with charge injection glitch from earlier ADG613 design
[image]
Charge injection on the sine wave inputs (sorry about the scope triggering)
[image]

So I am wondering is there anyway to add a compensation circuit to guarantee that glitches will be kept to a minimum? I was wondering if I could put capacitors on the output of the in-amps to absorb some of the excess injection.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with charge injection? If it's consistent pulse to pulse, then it's just an offset. Put small Cs to ground at the outputs of the switch to take the sting out of it before the high frequency components upset any slow amplifiers downstream. If it's voltage dependent, then the effect will be a gain non-linearity, which you might be able to handle other ways. If it's inconsistent pulse to pulse, then you can't compensate it anyway, and you need a more reliable switch.

Comment: I would say it is consistent pulse to pulse but voltage dependent as well. My input is what I intend to measure (it changes to some degree) so I would say so it would depend on how steady the input is. If I put a 100pF caps on the output of the analog switch wouldn't that be 30pC/100pF = 300mV  offset!

Comment: Can you cancel the injected charge by generating a time-aligned complementary version of "trigger", using it to drive an extra cap antiphase into the switch output? Size of the cap would be charge injected divided by voltage swing on "trigger."

Comment: @FrontRanger Forgive me, but are you saying to have an inverted 'trigger' square wave drive a capacitor that is hooked up to the output of the mux?

Comment: Yes. The source of the injected charge is the voltage swing of "trigger" multiplied by some parasitic capacitance between the switch control terminal and switch output. If you can approximate that capacitance and connect it between the switch output and the inverted "trigger", then ideally the switch output becomes a small-signal ground with respect to "trigger."

Comment: @FrontRanger That is an incredible idea. Complementary version of trigger, meaning logic inverted 5V => 0V or like gain inverted where 5V=>-5V? Would it matter?

Comment: Since you're AC-coupling it, the DC value of your complementary "trigger" signal would not matter, only the swing. If it works, let me know and I'll convert this comment to an answer.

Comment: @FrontRanger I am not sure if the capacitance is being matched properly or not, but it seems to be adding some glitches!  Looks like the trick must be to find some way to properly balance the trigger signal with the parasitic capacitance.

https://imgur.com/a/0czfmfb

Comment: @Jirhska I can't contribute much to the discussion except to note that manufacturers (like Burr Brown) are aware of and able to create charge-balanced MOSFET analog switches. They are expensive because of the work and the smaller market. But you can get them. Some analog switch ICs also exist that claim to be "balanced well." But I consider them poorly balanced despite the claim. Their numbers are just too high. Good ones will have less than \$1\:\text{pC}\$ residual imbalance after an ON/OFF cycle.

Comment: @Jirhska There are a few non-idealities that might produce the glitches. One is that the actual cap value may not match the rated charge injection value. Try sweeping the value to see if you can get a better match. Another issue is that the parasitic cap from the internal FETs will be somewhat signal dependent. This may not be a problem for you, since you seem to always switch at the zero-crossing. Yet another issue is that the timing of the true and complement "trigger" signals will be mismatched if generated by a simple inverter. Can you zoom way in to to the glitch?

Comment: @FrontRanger Yeah it seems to be that issue of matching to parasitics. Makes me wonder if a there is a better way to account for matching. A printed PCB could throw off any simulation matching I could do.

https://imgur.com/a/Hn2qsBy

Comment: @jonk Thanks! it seems off but often times some of the lower pC macro models seem to have up to .6V spikes! (this circuit was without the anitphase compensation) I tried simulating the ADG1219 at .1pC and got this:
https://imgur.com/a/mVaFRPx
A Cinj of .1pC should be 7uV not .6V so something else could be up here.